# Unity + Vuforia Export to Universal Windows Platform installer fails to install dependencies from .appx

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, uwp, vuforia

So I am building a test application using the basic Vuforia implementation in Unity for export to UWP (universal windows platform). I am running into issues when trying to install the packaged application on computers other than the one I developed it on.

When running the installer I get an error after initializing the install from the packaged .appx file:

[image: Error after initializing installer from packaged .appx file]

I run the installer on the computer that I built the unity application on, the installer works fine, it installs the application and runs perfectly and builds without errors.

However, when I try to move the .appx by itself to another computer and install it there, it is giving me this error on all computers I try.

> "App Installer failed to install package dependencies. Ask the developer for Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 package."

I tried to install the .NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 package with no avail from the [.NET Downloads page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)

FYI - the .appx file generated is the "Release" version for x64.

What am I missing here? How can I include the dependencies in the .appx file itself?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here? How can I include the dependencies in the .appx file itself?

The `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1` could not be Integrated into the app package directly. You need to install the dependencies package separately before install the app.

The store will install package dependencies to your machine automatically when install the app with Microsoft Store. So you could publish your dependent package to the store.

If you only want to install the app through the sideloading, you could make `PowerShell` command to install the package dependencies in the `Dependencies` folder where under the appx folder.

For Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, [related sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-related-set) can now be installed via App Installer. This allows distribution and deployment of related set app packages to users. And this is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-related-set) you could refer to.